# I can't download the pdf I created with Java (Springboot). How can I download?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, itext

When users click the download report button from the front end, I expect the report creation and download section in the backend to work, but it does not download the report even though it generates it.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/download/generateReport/{id}", produces = "application/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> generateFavoriteReport(@PathVariable String id) throws Exception {
        ReportRequest reportRequest= this.reportService.findByRequestWithId(id);                    
        ByteArrayInputStream in =  this.reportService.generateFavoriteReport(reportRequest);            
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FavoriteReport.pdf");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(new InputStreamResource(in));
}
```

When I try from Postman, I can see the report as output, but when I try it from Chrome or any browser, it appears like this and does not download. How can I download it? I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong but I'm about to get fired so I can't complete this please help :(

Chrome Result :
Response: 200 OK

%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 480/Height 160/Length 15631/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x��]`�֞�%���ʏt >�(*�"X@��`ED��l؟�X��������+*
"����2s���MB����)�|�93�wWJ)tq�:2➒��[�/ށ�*�O�X��pVw�>�CI�W���;��%�*dR������
?k9i{��jE����nHIT+C���U��ZE��$�~�x
�J
I(�B���0�H���@��2Z
�� 5bo&���^�
AIE #��١�$���K�q4
�t��2��/x�%���/�ȁV�f&�pJO��%���%Q��@�x"U���t�8،A)�n�Ț`���%]���0�Y5S��BR��67j�q��/��tCb��)�z�a1��]�[�*�lp�'���4��J��$L�֔�����Y/���������Q�F��'�TS�p ��(|&��3I3�g�[]� 1�c��'�;1X�/��b�����k!# �w�o@t[��i�� �WH%���.=��n�K.�s����l#�a�-�wؤ���j�իWϮ�������#HM'}���f�$|�F3� D奋*��"�*�#EI2�`4Z@ǗzB�h����Y�� F���E3j�:��U��:}ֻ���{�g<�Ȅ�{��͌��p�<�K�>T��T�����ի����XA���u� �G5�DL(��A�&�Kae���!qpip&Dr�v���̼�Vo�+,.�R\��c��_����uS�!pT�I�+Y
�n�

```
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=FavoriteReport.pdf");
headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
headers.add("Expires", "0");
```

I also added different methods of headers but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

In that way you just render the byte array in the client side
The current code works for me, you dont need to put anything in the controller

```
    File file = new File("MYPDFFILE.PDF");
   
    final myByte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

    final ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(myByte);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(data.length)
            .header("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
            .header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"")
            .body(resource);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even thou you added the "produces = "application/pdf" you need to set the content-type in the header:

headers.add("Content-type", "application/pdf");

The produces directive controllers "the mapped handler" for your content, but your code writes raw data, please see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-responseentity

```
@PostMapping(value = "/download/generateReport/{id}", produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> generateFavoriteReport(@PathVariable String id) throws Exception {
    ReportRequest reportRequest= this.reportService.findByRequestWithId(id);                    
    ByteArrayInputStream in =  this.reportService.generateFavoriteReport(reportRequest);            
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FavoriteReport.pdf");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
    headers.add("Content-type", "application/pdf");  
   
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(new InputStreamResource(in));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't "produces" set content-type header by itself?

Comment: One might think so, but in my experience across various versions of spring is that if you start messing with the ResponseEntity you are better safe than sorry to make sure it is all set. The above code "works for me" - but I haven't tested to remove the Content-type